# Delivery Optimization Service can't be disabled after the last Windows 10 Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, administrator, services, windows-services

I'm always disabling this service because it keeps using my whole bandwidth.. but after the October update, there is like a restriction or something because when I tried to disable it using the `services.msc` like usual, I got the message "Access is denied" so I wonder if there is another way to disable a service when we don't have the access (and yes, I'm already running everything as `administrator`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Disable Delivery Optimization via Group Policy or Registry Editor in Windows 10](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/disable-delivery-optimization-via-group-policy-or-registry-editor)

Disable Delivery Optimization via Registry Editor

Since this is a registry operation, it is recommended that you back up the registry or create a system restore point as necessary precautionary measures. Once done, you can proceed as follows:

Press Windows key + R to invoke the Run dialog.
In the Run dialog box, type `regedit` and hit Enter to open Registry Editor.

Navigate or jump to the registry key path below:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DoSvc
```

At the location, on the right pane, double-click the Start entry to modify it.
Type 4 in the Value data box.
Click OK to save the change.
Close the Registry Editor window.
Reboot your computer to save the changes.

[image]